# Allow only specific branch names

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket

In Bitbucket, I can set permissions for branches matching a specific wildcard. But is it also possible that branches that do *not* match that wildcard can be blocked?

Comment: I found this Plugin https://github.com/Parallels/atlassian-restrict-branch-model , but we have addition allowed Branch Names wich can not be specified in the model